# PHP compare values with HTML special characters

Tags: php

I am trying to compare rows from 2 PHP arrays like this...

```
if ($row1[$i] == $row2[$i]) {
    echo 'Rows match';
} else {
    echo 'Rows do not match';
}
```

This is working correctly until it comes across something that is encoded, so apostrophe is a good example. So the below 2 are not equal...

```
This is an apostrophe'
This is an apostrophe&#39;
```

I have tried using `htmlspecialchars_decode` to attempt to convert them before comparing but this is not working. How can I compare these 2 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `html_entity_decode()` with `ENT_QUOTES` flag

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

```
html_entity_decode('This is an apostrophe&#39;', ENT_QUOTES);
```